# How group issues by properties of linked issues in jira

Tags: jira

I have a base filter / JQL in jira in the form of a rich filter. I wanna show a pie chart or table (or literally anything else) and group them by the name of a linked issue.

To give a simplified example, lets assume a project A and a project B. Issues if project A are linked via "relates to" to issues of project A and B. My base filter is on issues of project B, and I wanna visualize how much work has been logged on issues project type B, per issue of A.

So the base filter could simply look like:

```
project = B
```

and I wanna visualize time spent (as logged on issues of B) per issue of A.